# Creative Commons Mix and Printed Materials

Tags: vector, creative-commons

Hello graphic design exchange.

I have a question about creative commons and its mix usage for printed materials.

As you know there are lots of websites offering free vectors for commercial uses. In my case, it is freepik.com. It says it allows commercial usage if we attribute them.

My question is how can we attribute on printed materials like business cards?

For example I design some business cards for my freelance customers and want to use some brush or shape from one element. Maybe I use lots of background elements seperately.

How can I attribute on business card for example?
For example a web banner, how can we attribute?
or a smaller project a logo and I like a shape vector and want to use by mixing other elements, how can I attribute these types of designs?

edit: this question marked as a duplicate, but I have different situation. On a magazine, there can be a copyright, on a poster, there can be a little statement, but on a business card design? For example floral vector backgrounds from a cc licensed file?

Comment: Welcome to GDE. I think you need to reword your question as it isn't very understandable. What do you mean exactly by "attribute on business card"?

Comment: You are touching on a very tricky and sore point... but indeed a very, very real problem. Here is pretty much the same Q: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27498/how-to-attribute-give-credit-to-creative-commons-copyleft-public-domain-content

Comment: I do not mean to be difficult, but I still think it is basically the same question, though I did not mention business cards in the other question. The point is something small, something printed. The answers do not really address this, but I think it is because this is a very sore and extremely difficult point, so in a way that is an answer in itself. There is a bounty on it now, maybe that would encourage someone to answer. I might actually have a go myself. I think the fundamental thing is to reconsider use of imagery...

Comment: What would you suggest personally ? there are lots of vectors for commercial to use :) freepik.com.