# How to attribute Creative Commons art on a T-Shirt

Tags: copyright, legal, creative-commons

I'm creating a T-shirt using an image licenced under [CC BY-SA 4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0). The main problem I'm facing is how do I attribute the image used? Do I put the attribution on the site I sell the T-shirt on, or do I put it right on the T-shirt?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! I think your question has already been answered here: [How to attribute, give credit to creative commons/copyleft/public domain content for web/print?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/27498/8708)

Comment: You pretty much need to ask the person that created the artwork. This is what of the more frustrating aspects of CC licenses.

Comment: JohnB, its a bit different. That post didn't answer my question. Its more of a difference between things that are made to be sold online and those that aren't.

Comment: This question would also be appropriate for [opensource.se].

Answer (score 0):

I would attribute the CC license holder on the inner label of the t-shirt.